# OnItemCommand Event Doesn't Fire In ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

`OnItemCommand` event **doesn't** fire when I `click` the button inside `ItemTemplate` ? I tried something but nothing happened. Did I forgot to put something  or something else ? What should I do to fix it?

aspx page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ShowPostsListView" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ShowPostsListView_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="ShowPostsListView_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="AddCommentButton" CssClass="addCommentButton" runat="server" Text="Add Comment" CommandName="Add Comment" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

code behind page:

```
protected void ShowPostsListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Add Comment")
    {
                 ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I fixed it adding `UseSubmitBehavior="false"` to Button Control property.I don't know why this fix the problem. If anyone can explain it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same thing would be to add an OnClick event handler to the button as so:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ShowPostsListView" runat="server"    
 OnItemDataBound="ShowPostsListView_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="AddCommentButton" CssClass="addCommentButton" 
        OnClick="addCommentButton_OnClick" runat="server" 
        Text="Add Comment"  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

And then:

```
protected void addCommentButton_OnClick(obejct sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: this is an alternate but doesnt explain the question

Answer (score 0):

have you set the eventhandling in webconfig false to get rid of the error, if you did that please change it back to same way or make it true, and before binding the data to your listview jst add

```
if(!isPostBack)
ListView1.Databind();
```

i hope this will solve the problem, and your event will fire